# How to download File with open-feign

Tags: java, feign

How to download `File` with **open-feign**, it's possible?
for example:

```
@RequestLine("GET /file")
File from (@Param("param") String param);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Spring?

You can use this code:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/multipart/download/{fileId}",
        method = GET)
MultipartFile[] download(@PathVariable("fileId") String fileId);
```

Check the tutorial in the [official Github](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form).